# Range and Graph of a function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Let $$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$

State the range and plot its graph wherever the function is defined.

I got the range and $f'(x)$, but I cannot find the sign of it to predict the increasing/decreasing of the graph. Please help.

Comment: Here is a picture https://www.geogebra.org/classic/rbrcj2an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of this function $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x$ is $(-\infty, -1) \cup (0,\infty)$
Range of this function is $(1,\infty)$. For this $$L_1=\lim_{x \to 0} (1+1/x)^x= \exp[\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln (1+1/x)]$$ By L-Hospital
$$L_1=\lim_{x \to 0}\exp[ \frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{1/x}]=\exp[ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{1+x}]=1.$$

Next
$$L_2=\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} (1+1/x)^x= \exp[\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} x \ln (1+1/x)]$$ $$L_2=\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}\exp[ \frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{1/x}]=$$
By L-Hospital
$$L_2=\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}\exp[ \frac{\ln(1+1/x)}{1/x}]=\exp[ \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \frac{x}{1+x}]=e.$$

Next $$L_3=\lim_{x \to -1^{-}} \ln (1+1/x)^x=\lim_{h \to 0} [1+1/(-1-h)^{-1-h}=\lim_{h\to 0} (1+1/h)^{1+h}=\infty$$

Additionally, $f(x)=(1+1/x)^x$ is an increasing function in its domain. See $$f'(x)=(1+1/x)e^{-1/(1+x)}>0, x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (0, \infty)$$, see the graph of $f(x)$ below.

[image]$$

Comment: How is this an increasing function in its domain? Compare f(-5) and f(1.1) from the graph given above. f(-5)>f(1.1). Not increasing.

Comment: It is increasing in (-infinity,-1) and in (0,infinity) but not in the union of these intervals.

Comment: Oh! yes @Lawrence Mano

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\implies \log(f(x))=x \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}$$ Now, play with some inequalities.